# React : The path to the "404 not found" page if there is an error does not work

Tags: reactjs, custom-error-pages

I am trying to redirect to an error page if a product ID is not found in a React project. I then find myself faced with a blank page and this error:

[image]

I created a Hook with UseEffect to retrieve data from an API

And here is the code for the page that should either return the products or the error page:

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Rating from "../../Components/Rating";
import Slider from "../../Components/Slider";

import Tags from "../../Components/Tags";
import Host from "../../Components/Host";

import Error from "../Error";

import Accordion from "../../Components/Accordion";
import "./logement.css";
import { useFetch } from "../../utils/hooks";

function Logement() {
  const { logementId } = useParams();

  const {
    data: logement,
    isLoading,
    error,
  } = useFetch(`http://localhost:8000/logements/${logementId}`);

  if (isLoading) return <h1>LOADING...</h1>;

  if (error) {
    return <Error />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="logements__page">
      <div className="logements__wrapper">
        <Slider slides={logement.pictures} />
        <div className="content">
          <div className="informations">
            <h1>{logement.title}</h1>
            <p className="logement__location">{logement.location}</p>
            <div className="tags__wrapper">
              {logement.tags.map((tag, index) => (
                <Tags key={index} getTag={tag} />
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="rating__host">
            <Rating rating={logement.rating} />
            <Host host={logement.host} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="collapsible">
          <Accordion title="Description" content={logement.description} />
          <Accordion title="Equipement" content={logement.equipments} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Logement;
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Please see [ask]. Errors should not be presented as images.

Answer (score 0):

`{(logement?.tags || []).map((tag, index) => (`

Try it, and your problem will be solved!

Comment: I have the same issue, if I write a wrong id in the url after "logements/"

Comment: **First**, To fix your error image, `Cannot read property from undefined`, problem is `logement.tags` can be undefined, like `null`, you can not read anything from undefined or null. -> To fix it, set a default value for `logement.tags` with `logement.tags || []`.


**Second**: your expectation is `redirect to error page` if logement tag not found, or anything happen with it. Check your `useFetch` hook's logic and return error's value when not found.